# javascript - discord.js slash command builder not registering commands or displaying commands in discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I already have another slash command not using the slash command builder that works, so I know all the authorization scopes are fine. When I try to register the command with the slash command builder, I don't get an error, but it doesn't show up on discord.
Code:
*index.js*

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField, PermissionsBitField, Embed, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle} = require('discord.js');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { ActionRowBuilder, Events, Collection, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');




const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ],
});

client.commands = new Collection();

const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    console.log(interaction);
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    console.log(interaction);
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});
//Code cut off
```

ticket-setup.js (setting up slash command builder)

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder, PermissionsBitField, PermissionFlagsBits} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ticket-setup')
        .setDescription('Open a Ticket')
        .setDMPermission(false),
    async execute(interaction) {

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Contact Moderation')
            .setDescription('Create a ticket and contact the moderators with the button below.')
            .setColor('Blue');
        const ticketBtn = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('ticketBtn')
            .setLabel('Open Ticket')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

         const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(ticketBtn)

         await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
    }
    
}
```

I've looked at all the docs but was unable to find an answer. Trying to register slash commands without the builder works fine, but I am unable to do it with this.

**EDIT**
Attached images of file directories to better understand the code:
[directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZg7G.png)

Comment: Restart your Discord client and they should be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering the commands as `Application commands` which can take up to an hour (or longer, not sure about the exact timeframe) to update due to Discord API limitations.
`Guild commands` however are updated instantly for the specified guild(s).
Without changing the majority of your code you could register your commands as `Guild commands` in the following way:

`await client.guilds.cache.get(YOUR GUILD ID).commands.set(command.data.name, command);`

But this is not the preferred way to do so according to Discord. They have written their own tutorial [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#guild-commands)